# How does facebook show the information icon prompt to install messenger?

Tags: html, facebook, popup

Using FireFox 29.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 this morning, I visited facebook.com and saw a kind of pop-up notification prompting me to install FaceBook Messenger.  The pop up was anchored from an "i" (information) icon next the the URL/location bar. See screen shot below.

How is this accomplished in the HTML for that page?

[image]